# Getting a 500 Internal Server Error during CSV download in Oracle APEX and need to extend the timeout (Oracle APEX 21.1.0)

Tags: tomcat, oracle-apex

Currently, I'm experiencing a "500 Internal Server Error" while downloading a CSV file. The error page is displayed by Apache Tomcat.

The target data is a 45MB CSV file, which I confirmed by generating the file using SQL*Plus. I'm attempting to download the CSV file from the APEX interface using Interactive Reports' "Actions - Download" option.

The error occurs approximately 15 minutes after initiating the download.

In my investigation, I couldn't find the "Timeout" parameter in the etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file. Additionally, in the environment I'm working with, multiple Apache Tomcat instances are installed, and the above config file showed signs of being modified by someone else. It might take some time to confirm if I can add the timeout configuration without interfering with others.

Ideally, I would prefer to modify only the configuration related to the APEX instance I am running, to avoid affecting others.

Where can I find the configuration file specific to the APEX instance to make the necessary timeout modification? Please let me know if any additional information is needed.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How do you know it's a timeout problem? What does the Tomcat log file say about the error?

Comment: Thank you for your response.

I have noticed that I always encounter an Internal Server Error after leaving the browser in a loading state for a while. This time, I measured the time it takes for the error message to appear and found that it occurs after approximately 15 minutes, which led me to suspect a timeout issue.

Furthermore, I see a "Broken Pipe" error in the Catalina logs, but it seems that there is no relevant information in the Tomcat logs. However, there is a possibility that I might have overlooked the Tomcat logs, so I will double-check them.

Thank you once again.

Comment: 'Broken pipe' at the server end during a download means that the *client*, i.e. the browser, has closed the connection.

Comment: Thank you! I have searched online and understood that there are several conditions that can result in a "Broken pipe" error. In my case, I didn't interrupt the download or experience any network instability. I also learned that there could be a possibility of timeouts or download restrictions imposed by the browser. However, I have successfully downloaded files of around 150MB in size in my environment, so it seems that this aspect is not a problem.

Comment: I am currently looking for the storage location of the Apache Tomcat logs. It may take a little while, I apologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: If the browser had timed-out the download, or failed it as too big, it would have show that to the user, instead of reporting the HTTP 500 status. This is rather mysterious. What was the Tomcat doing when it got the 'broken pipe'? Maybe talking to something else?

Comment: Let me first report the current situation. In the Tomcat logs, only the "500 Internal Server Error" was reported. In the Catalina logs, there was an error stating "ora-01013 user requested cancel of current operation". The browser displayed an error page from ORACLE REST Data Service.

Comment: Until last week, the "broken pipe" error was appearing in the Catalina log files. Today, I added a "Validation query" to the configuration, so it might be due to its impact, or it could be an error that was unrelated to the timeout issue from the beginning. I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: I will search for "How to extend the timeout for communication between DB and Apache." Is that correct?

Comment: I have no idea whether it's correct. You seem to be jumping to more conclusions to me. You need to find the actual exception in the logs, and post it here.

Comment: I'm sorry. I seem to be rushing to conclusions and not reading Tomcat and Java logs correctly. I will carefully examine the logs while researching and write a comment. Your feedback is very helpful to me. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you! The issue has been resolved, and I have improved my ability to solve problems by reading Java and Tomcat logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In conclusion, the default value for the timeout until the completion of SQL queries in Oracle REST Data Services was 15 minutes. In my environment, I had not set the value (jdbc.statementTimeout), which caused the timeout issue. This value can be specified in default.xml, and I resolved the problem by executing the following command:
java -jar ords.war set-property jdbc.statementTimeout 1800
I would like to express my gratitude to user207421 for helping me resolve the issue.